# Matching against multidimensional arrays

Tags: php

I am trying to get the results of the arrays that dont exisit inside of another array. For example $airports_apex code does not match with $airports_if then you the array should return

```
        array('id' => '56','code' => 'QQQ','airport_name' => 'Seattle1, WA'),
        array('id' => '56','code' => 'DDD','airport_name' => 'Seattle2, WA'),
        array('id' => '56','code' => 'TTT','airport_name' => 'Seattle3, WA'),
        array('id' => '56','code' => 'FFF','airport_name' => 'Seattle4, WA'),
        array('id' => '56','code' => 'JJJ','airport_name' => 'Seattle5, WA'),
        array('id' => '56','code' => 'YYY','airport_name' => 'Seattle6, WA'),
        array('id' => '56','code' => 'MMM','airport_name' => 'Seattle7, WA'),
```

Since I am unseting anything else that matches, but for some reason it does not do that.

I thought using array_diff_assoc() would have been the direction to go but i keep getting a "Array to string conversion" error so I tried this method that you see in my fullcode.

Any suggestions?

This is the full code.

```
$airports_if = array(
    array('id' => '0','code' => '--','airport_name' => ''),
    array('id' => '1','code' => 'LAX','airport_name' => 'Los Angeles International, CA'),
    array('id' => '2','code' => 'APA','airport_name' => 'Arapahoe, CO'),
    array('id' => '3','code' => 'APF','airport_name' => 'Naples, FL'),
    array('id' => '4','code' => 'ASE','airport_name' => 'Aspen, CO'),
    array('id' => '5','code' => 'AUS','airport_name' => 'Austin, TX'),
    array('id' => '6','code' => 'BAK','airport_name' => 'Columbus, IN'),
    array('id' => '7','code' => 'BJC','airport_name' => 'Jeffco, CO'),
);


$airports_apex = array(
    array('id' => '0','code' => '--','airport_name' => ''),
    array('id' => '54','code' => 'BCT','airport_name' => 'Boca Raton, FL'),
    array('id' => '55','code' => 'BED','airport_name' => 'Bedford, MA'),
    array('id' => '56','code' => 'BFI','airport_name' => 'Seattle, WA'),
    array('id' => '56','code' => 'QQQ','airport_name' => 'Seattle1, WA'),
    array('id' => '56','code' => 'DDD','airport_name' => 'Seattle2, WA'),
    array('id' => '56','code' => 'TTT','airport_name' => 'Seattle3, WA'),
    array('id' => '56','code' => 'FFF','airport_name' => 'Seattle4, WA'),
    array('id' => '56','code' => 'JJJ','airport_name' => 'Seattle5, WA'),
    array('id' => '56','code' => 'YYY','airport_name' => 'Seattle6, WA'),
    array('id' => '56','code' => 'MMM','airport_name' => 'Seattle7, WA'),
);

foreach ($airports_if as $key=>$value) {
        foreach ($airports_apex as $ap_key => $ap_value){
            if ($value['code'] == $ap_value['code']){
                unset($airports_apex[$key]);
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're unsetting from `$airports_apex` using the key from `$airports_if`.  Try

```
foreach ($airports_if as $key=>$value) {
        foreach ($airports_apex as $ap_key => $ap_value){
            if ($value['code'] == $ap_value['code']){
                unset($airports_apex[$ap_key]);
            }
        }
}
```